# Ubuntu Server 16.04 vs 20.04 memory usage

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, ram, memory-usage

It seems like Ubuntu 20.04 consumes 4 GB of memory on virtual box while Ubuntu 16.04 consumes very very less. This is a new VM, only the OS was installed.

The memory requirements for Ubuntu 16.04 is 1.5 GB and 20.04 requires 4 GB.

Any idea why 20.04 consumes consumes so much memory? I'm thinking of not using ubuntu 20.04 on virtual box anymore.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. What are the VMs doing? Which file system is being used? Are the VMs on the same host? At what point are you checking memory consumption? What processes load at startup? What is the storage size for each VM? I could ask a thousand additional questions that would make it possible to mathematically determine “expected memory consumption”, but this should be a decent start 

Comment: it's a new VM. Only the OS was setup.

Comment: There are still six unanswered questions … 

Comment: Your title mentions server, however you are aware not all readers of questions will see that when reading your question? (*your question doesn't state server/desktop, speaking only of release differences*). Any details in the heading need to also be contained within the question itself, as browsers used can vary & title details may not be seen on an open page when question is read.

Comment: I have 20.04 servers that consume on average less than 300MB of RAM with a 1GB limit.  RAM consumption is very dependent on what your server is running, etc. so this is still extraordinarily broad a question.  What is running on your server?  How frequently are those running services being used by external clients?  Need a lot more answers to questions before we can even begin to answer here.

Comment: isn't the question mute? 16.04 is EOL

Comment: Could you please in your post include the output of the following command, to see which processes consume the most memory: `ps aux | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 4) | head -11 | less -SEX`. Just complaining about memory usage without any evidence doesn't give us anything to work with.

Comment: Also, please include the output of `free -h` to let us know how much memory is actually being used.

Answer (score 3):

Well one thing-- Ubuntu 16.04 used the Unity desktop. Since 2017, Ubuntu has used GNOME. GNOME has a reputation for being heavy on memory compared to other desktop environments.

Other than that, you are talking about releases that have half a dozen other releases and 4 years between them. There's a lot of differences.

If you want a lighter DE, use Xubuntu or Lubuntu - they have lighter RAM requirements.

Comment: I meant the servers actually. Not desktop environments

Comment: Ubuntu Server definitely does not need 4GB of RAM...

Comment: @User Yes, server is mentioned in the title and yet in the body all you mention are the **desktop** versions recommend hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes little sense, as it doesn't mention Server or Desktop, but you list the requirements of the desktop version as your reason for the question?

The server docs refer the minimum requirements as

> This version supports four 64-bit architectures:
>
> - amd64 (Intel/AMD 64-bit)
> - arm64 (64-bit ARM)
> - ppc64el (POWER8 and POWER9)
> - s390x (IBM Z and LinuxONE)
>
> The recommended system requirements are:
>
> - CPU: 1 gigahertz or better
> - RAM: 1 gigabyte or more
> - Disk: a minimum of 2.5 gigabytes

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation

where RAM isn't mentioned.  Instead you appear to have got the mininums from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements and the *Ubuntu Desktop Edition* section of the document, instead of Server area which doesn't mention RAM requirements (*they vary depending on usage*)